# Exclude an external stylesheet appended from a jQuery external file

Tags: jquery, wordpress, external, stylesheet

I'm building a website for a client and at a certain point I had to add a third part jQuery file in order to add some products to my page. The problem is that this very script is adding to my file his own stylesheet in this way:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});

jQuery('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://pathToTheScript/style-products-v2.css">');
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to exclude this function from the script. I can download locally and I can get rid of the file manually, but the problem is that this third part updates regularly this page, adding a ton a new products.
I'm working in a wordpress environment, so my question is: is there any way to exclude the file with another script so I can replace it with my old stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("link").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href")=="pathToTheScript/style-products-v2.css"){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Because this link is inserted by another script...
The file name of the .css file may change in the future's third party script updates...

You should do this by using a regular expression to target the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("link").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href")==/http:\/\/domain\.com\/pathToTheScript\/.*\.css/){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

This will remove link element that has an href value like: `http://domain.com/pathToTheScript/ (whatever) .css`:

Example:
`http://domain.com/pathToTheScript/style-products-v2.css`
`http://domain.com/pathToTheScript/style-products-v3.css`
`http://domain.com/pathToTheScript/improved-style.css`
`http://domain.com/pathToTheScript/anything.css`

Side note:
in the part of the path you keep in the regex (the part you're sure will not change), you have to escape `/` and `.` like this `\/` and this: `\.`.
You can test your regular expression here: https://regex101.com/#javascript

**Just to be clear**
You have to use the path to the CSS file !
Not the path to the .js file that injects it.
;)

Comment: Does it work in another script? I mean I will add this piece of code in another script in my footer (I'm running the script that I showed in the middle of the page, right before the div which contains the module).
So my question is how can I hook an external script like that:

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Grills</h1>
  <script src="http://myscript-v2.js"></script>
  <div id="myproduct"></div><script> function {
doSomethingWith#myproduct</script>
 </div>

Comment: Yes, this code chunk will run on document ready... Even if it is in an external js.

Comment: lud1977's answer does exactly the same thing as mine... But is more concise. ;)

Comment: It «targets» the link element based on its href value. The only thing that may be a problem in the future is to be sure that this css file name will not change on the script's future updates... ;)

Comment: Cool! But what if, for example, the link to the script is something like that:

http://www.hosting.com/js/myscript.js but it calls the style with the append method:

 jQuery('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hosting.com/css/mystyle.css">');

It means that I want to exclude the file from another folder which is a higher lever to the script which calls it?

Comment: Use the part of the URL your sure not to change... Like `hosting.com` only... But be aware if you load other .css (that you want to keep) from that source ! ;)

Comment: Something like `/http:\/\/hosting\.com\/.*\.css/`. Try your possibilities with the regex tester i mentionned. About your question : **«exclude the file from another folder which is a higher lever to the script which calls it»** : There is no worry about it. We use the a part of the href value to target an element **in your page**. It doesn't matter where it is located.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work.. Could it be because I'm not calling the script? The structure is like that inside the page:

<script src="http://hostingservice/js/script.js"></script>

But later the external link is call in this other way:

append('<link href="http://hostingservice/css/style.js">';

Could it be the problem why I'm not able to remove the link?

Comment: Hew... Maybe the injection happens after our trial to remove... I don't know. Maybe try to use `setTimeout()` function to delay the removal script ???

Comment: Actually, it is working your very first version of the code, the one with the .each function for the links! So thank you for helping me, your very first clue was right!

Comment: I updated in this way... So the answer will be clear for others. ;)

Comment: How can I do that? I guess I just did

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
jQuery('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="pathToTheScript/style-products-v2.css">');
```

from the script.

Comment: I explained that I can't modify the script locally since the third part company will update the script frequently

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test, but something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('link[href="pathToTheScript/style-products-v2.css"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: Great! the only problem is that is an external script that I added in this way:

(In the middle of a page call product.php)

<div class="container-fluid"> <h1>Grills</h1> <script src="http://myscript-v2.js"></script>; <div id="myproduct"></div><script> function { doSomethingWith#myproduct</script> </div>

I need to hook the  <script src="http://myscript-v2.js">